# Checkbox class incremented in html and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamically generated checkbox based on JSON data and that is generated by jQuery. I need to dynamically generate checkbox class name. Here is my code that is generated a checkbox

```
<td>
  <label class="switch">
    <input
      id="chkEnabled"
      checked
      type="checkbox"
      onchange="checkedorUncheked(' + result.data.resultSet[i].id + ',' + count + ')" class="chkEnabled"' + count +' >
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label >
</td>
```

Here class="chkEnabled"' + count +' I'm incrementing class value but when I call the method `checkedorUncheked` I get count value but not getting the class value. Here I console it

```
` this.checkedorUncheked = function (item, item2) {
    //console.log('.chkEnabled' + item2);
    $('.chkEnabled' + item2).change(function () {
        console.log(item2);`
```

I'm not able to console inside change event because of class name.

Comment: you have to do event delegation with their parent element

Comment: can you give some example I'm not very good in jquery yes I'm reading what you suggest .

Comment: using diffrents classnames is not a good practice too... what is tha parent element for all this inputs ?

Comment: I use table and inside <td> i have this checkbox

Comment: <td><label class="switch"><input id="chkEnabled" checked  type = "checkbox" onchange="checkedorUncheked(' + result.data.resultSet[i].id + ',' + count + ')" class="chkEnabled"' + count +' ><span class="slider round"></span></label ></td>

Comment: @Mister Jojo  so you are suggesting I select id instead of class?

Comment: yes, and ID must be UNIQUE for each element, as class name should be used for group elements

Comment: *"I need to dynamically generate checkbox class name. ... I'm incrementing class value"*: why? That sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: and he have **2** event listerner for 'change' on the same element...

Comment: Ok I 'm dynamically generate Id but its not working can you see My HTML is ok  <input id="chkEnabled"' + count +'>

Comment: how do you "dynamically generated checkbox based on JSON data" ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when HTML elements are dynamically generated, you need to rebind the events of the generated element

Try

```
this.checkedorUncheked = function (item, item2) {
//console.log('.chkEnabled' + item2);
$('.chkEnabled' + item2).on('change',function () {  
    console.log(item2);
```

Use on() method instead of directly using .change(), but in comments as suggested don't generate class, generate Id instead and use the same.

then code becomes

```
 $('#chkEnabled' + item2).on('change',function () {  
    console.log(item2);
```

**UPDATE**

```
  <input
  id=' + result.data.resultSet[i].id + '
  checked
  type="checkbox"
  onchange="checkedorUncheked(this);" count=' + count +' >
<span class="slider round"></span>


function checkedorUncheked (e){
   var itme1 = $(e).attr('id'); /// for id
   var item2 = $(e).attr('count'); // count 


    if($(e).prop('checked') == true){
    //do something
    }
 else{
   /// do another
  }
}
```

Comment: @RifatMurtuza check if get value of item2

Comment: @RifatMurtuza I think you dont need on('change'), do whatever directly on checkedorUncheked

Comment: How can I get value item1,item2 because first I did in your way but i need this two value as I said I'm dynamically generated this checkbox . so every time i change event I have to change the value 0 or 1

Comment: thanks for your answer I did it earlier it worked for single value not dynamic

Comment: @RifatMurtuza good to know, but still, I have updated answer to get item1 and item2 values